# How change file coding from windows-1251 to utf-8

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, xml-parsing

I have xml file and I need to convert the text that I get from it:

I just start to write code, but I don't know how to realize this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path);             

XDocument documentcode = XDocument.Load(text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to specify the correct encoding when reading:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
 XDocument documentcode = XDocument.Parse(text);  // not load.
```

You probably don't have to do anything special when writing.